# Laravel changing function/text of a button depending on value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 and I have a button "Enable" that once pressed sets a flag in the DB to 1. This all works fine with my code below:

Blade view

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/cms/user/' . $user->id . '/flag', 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
                                {!! Form::hidden('flagged', !$user->flagged) !!}
                                {!! Form::submit('Flag', ['class' => 'btn btn-success'])!!}
                                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Controller

```
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @Middleware({"auth"})
 *
 * @param  int $id
 * @Put ("cms/user/{user}/flag",as="cms.users.update.flag")
 * @return Response
 */
    public function updateflag($id)
        {
            $user = User::find($id);
            //dd(Input::get('flagged'));
            $user->flagged = Input::get('flagged');

            $user->save();

            Session::flash('message', 'Successfully flagged idea!');
            return redirect()->route('cms.users.index');
        }
```

Now what I'm trying to work out is changing the button once the user flags it. I.e.: The first time the button should say "Enable" (DB value is 0). Then I press the button and it updates the flag in the DB to 1 (which works fine).

But now, after the button is pressed, how do I change the button text to "Disable" so I can then disable the user on pressing the button. Kind of like an on/off switch that I can enable/disable the user but updating the button text and function based on what the flagged value is in the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a boolean variable to the view (apparently you already have a variable that contains this information):

```
return redirect()->route('cms.users.index')->with(['flag' => $flag]);
```

Then in view make an if/else:

```
@if($flag)
    {!! Form::submit('Enable', ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'disabled' => 'disabled']) !!}
@else
    {!! Form::submit('Enable', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) !!}
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I missed using an `if` statement. The "disable" user button won't actually be disabled, it should still be clickable for the user and send 0 to the variable. Will accept this answer shortly.